# MVC Form just doesn't post if no radiobutton selected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a user registration form, with one set of radio buttons for the user's selected package.  The form first renders with none of the radio buttons selected, as I want it to.  However, if I don't select any option, the form merely doesn't post, based on some client side validation, yet there is no indication of what is wrong.  To me it's obvious, but to my users it definitely won't be.  How can I inform the user what is wrong?

The radio buttons are in a table, not a RadioButtonList, as I wanted a few columns per button, so there is no single control I can attach a validation message to.

Answer (score 1):

On the form:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="validate(this)" action="http://somewhere.there" >
```

And a simple validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 validate(form){
   if(!form.package[0].checked & !form.package[1].checked){
       alert("select something please");
       return false;
   }
</script>
```

Assuming that you check box are named 'package' and there are only two options.
The return false will stop the form being submitted if no checkboxes are selected.

There are of course more elegant ways of doing this, but this will work:-)

Comment: the form is already being validated by the jQuery validation automatically injected by MVC.  My problem is just that it isn't showing an error message for the radio buttons.  I could manually duplicate the validation just to get an error message, but that isn't very tidy.

Comment: Aah :-) then I need more code or description of the problem to be able to make sense of it.